# Updating a single attribute in Rails/route match issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update a single attribute ("status") when a link is clicked. I'm new to Rails and have gone through similar questions with no success.

I've defined a new method for this ("accept") which may or may not have been the best way to go about it. Here's the link (which is within a table showing all submissions):

```
<td><%= link_to submission, method: :accept, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
<i class="fa fa-check fa-border yes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %></td>
```

I've tried a couple of options for defining the method including this:

```
def accept
  @submission.update_attributes(:status, "accepted")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
  end
end
```

and this:

```
def accept
  @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
  if @submission.update_attributes(:status, "accepted")
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @submission
  end
end
```

The main error I get is "No route matches [POST] "/submissions/4"". But I would assume an update like this would be PUT or PATCH so I'm not sure where I'm indicating it should be POST. I'm guessing I need to *either* create a POST route *or* somehow indicate it should be PUT or PATCH, but I'm not sure how to go about those.

Help appreciated; as I said, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When new method is defined , don't forget to create related route in routes.rb

Usually PUT/Patch request on "/controller/:id" will route to update method. 
In your case, you havent created route to you accept method.

> routes.rb

```
post '/accept_status_change' => 'your_controller#accept' , as: :accept_status_change
```

> views

```
<td><%= link_to accept_status_change_path, method: :accept, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
<i class="fa fa-check fa-border yes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %></td>
```

Comment: Thank you! This didn't fix it in its entirety, but was what I needed to move past the block. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)..just like **like/share** .
For example,User will click the link,which will submit the user accepted check in the db and will get a small update the view saying "Thank you for accepting."

```
##add accept in the form,can add remote:true to update view with small message div
<%= button_to accept_user_choice_path(current_user) , method:'post' do %>
   Accept <span class="fa fa-check btn btn-xs"></span>
<% end %>


##create a route
##use using member inside users resources to get user id
 member { post : accept_user_choice }

##in your controller add the code to accept/toggle user clicks
  def accept_user_choice 
    ##you can also set yes/no and pass the same to controller in the url
    ##value = params[:type] == "yes" ? 1 : -1
    @submission.update_attributes(:status, "accepted")
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Submission was successfully updated."
  end
```